# Reanaming xcode project having older test file

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-approval

I have a old project EmojiMaker and now i have renamed the project as Emoji Maker Pro.The display name, bundle id and other files have been renamed.There is a test folder with same old name,i have also renamed to new one ,but the .m file still has old filename.Will it create any issue while the project to app store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0):

no no any issue create for that but you verify

click on project then show in right side identify and type in select proper location of your project.. so no issue generate.

Comment: no, in xcode project navigator in project name clicked.

Comment: there is a Emoji_MakerTests.m file in which the interface name says  @interface Emoji_MakerTests : XCTestCase this interface has not been renamed as my new folder name is Emoji Maker Pro

Comment: select folder if that available name Emoji Maker Pro

Comment: U mean in identity and type ,under location?there are various options which one to choose?

Comment: at identity and type changed.But not changing test file.m

Comment: interface Emoji_MakerTests : XCTestCase

end
I have changed .m file but containing code not changing